# Set theory (A\C) \ (B\C) = (A\B)\C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Very difficult question. Can't make sides equal after multiple manipulations.This one is lost on me. Help a fellow human out. Thank you.

Comment: Have you drawn a Venn diagram? That often helps clarify what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** You could also write $A \backslash C$ as $A \cap C^c$ and work with unions and intersections. Use the facts that intersection distributes over union and that $C^c \cap C = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $a\in (A\setminus C)\setminus (B\setminus C)$ means that $a\in A\setminus C$ but not in $B\setminus C$, i.e., $a\in A$ but not $C$.